# Socket.io works fine over HTTP but fails to make a connection over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

So, i've just updated my site to use HTTPS, and when i did that all my sockets broke.

I updated 
socket = io.connect( 'http://x.x.x.x:8081' );

to
socket = io.connect( 'https://x.x.x.x:8081', {secure: true} );

but that doesn't do it.

I'm using apache and the SSL cert is LetsEncrypt, so not self signed.

It looks as though as if the socket.io is still trying to connect over HTTP, while it forces HTTPS.

I know this is not much information to go on. Please let me know if i can add any more logs that would make the issue more clear.

My NodeServer.js:

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server);
io.set('transports',['xhr-polling']);
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
        console.log( "New client !" );

        client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
                console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );
                //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
                io.sockets.emit( 'message', data);
        });

        client.on( 'doTrade', function( data ) {
                //console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );
                io.sockets.emit( 'doTrade', data );
        });
});

server.listen( 8081 );
```

Comment: how are you creating your server ? are you using express ?

Comment: See above......

Comment: your server is still running on `http`. Now you'll have to create `https` server

Comment: you've got `.key` and `.crt` files right ?

Comment: Yes, i have cert / chain / fullchain / privkey files. In PEM format

Comment: you'll have to create an `https` server now. Check my answer

Comment: I'll try this..

Comment: make certain you handle case of clients connecting to your http such that you force those over to https

Answer (score 0):

Previously your server was running on `http` and now as you want to connect to your server with `https`.

You'll to create an `https` server.

This is how you do that

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('pathToYourKeyFile/[KeyFile.key]', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('PathToCertFile/[Crt.crt]', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(8081);
```

Now you should successfully be able to connect with this server with `socket`

Comment: personally I use nginx to terminate TLS which is where I force http to become https ... in your answer how do clients who connect using http get toggled over to https ?  would that require creation of a http server  listening to 80 to get client boosted over to https

Comment: they won't be able to connect in this case

Comment: but yeah, if you've `ngnix` obviously you can redirect requests to `https`

Comment: var http = require('http');
http.createServer(app).listen(80);  var forceSsl = require('express-force-ssl');  app.use(forceSsl);    this allows http yet makes them become https

Comment: so this will redirect all http to https ?

Comment: I'm now getting a tunnel error. Any idea what the cause of that might be?